# Command to get number before % in linux

Tags: linux, sed, awk

In linux I use `df -k | tail -1` command & the output is

```
                     1717567488 1616255744 101311744  95% /home/asimon
```

I want to get **95** (just before %) out of it.

Any commands?

Comment: If you wish to "update with your answer", please do so _as an answer_.

Comment: @Oded: in other machine my command was not working

Comment: What's your point? I am saying that if you want to explain what you ended up doing, you should do so as an answer to your own question, not as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possible solution:

```
sed 's/^.*[[:blank:]]\([[:digit:]]*\)\%.*$/\1/'
```

It cuts out the complete line and replaces it with the match (which is zero or more digits preceded by blank and followed by percentage). Note that if there was no match you'll get the complete input line back.

Answer (score 1):

Your `df -k | tail -1` command may return different filesystem information over time. You should probably select which filesystem you want through another method:

```
df -k | grep asimon
```

or

```
cd /home/asimon && df -k .| tail -1
```

or

```
df -k /home/asimon | tail -1
```

When it comes to selecting just the field you want, `awk(1)` is good for that:

```
df -k /home/asimon | tail -1 | tr -d '%' | awk '{print $5;}'
```

Or to ditch the `tail(1)` call, use `awk(1)`'s pattern matching:

```
$ df -k /home | tr -d '%' | awk '/home/ {print $5;}'
39
```

Comment: +1 for pattern matching with AWK, that's a better solution than tail.

Answer (score 1):

In awk you can use something like this -

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat text6
                    1717567488 1616255744 101311744  95% /home/asimon
[jaypal~/Temp]$ awk '{print substr($(NF-1),1,2);}' text6
95
```

**Update**

Just realized if the value is single digit then it won't work. The following command would -

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat text6
                    1717567488 1616255744 101311744  95% /home/asimon
                    1717567488 1616255744 101311744  5% /home/asimon
[jaypal~/Temp]$ awk '{ print $(NF-1) }' text6 | tr -d '%'
95
5
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
df -k | sed '$!d;/%/{s/%.*//;s/.*\s//}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to not use 'df' for this, and use 'stat'. Use -c to show free and total blocks, and construct an expression to pipe to bc to get a percentage:

```
$ stat --file-system  -c 100*\(1-%f/%b\) /| bc -l
2.55971958854837098100
```

compare:

```
$ df -k /
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1            480617176  12302452 443900724   3% /
```

There's some slight disagreement because of rounding and I'm not sure what exactly df counts as free...

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can try

```
df -k | tail -1 |  cut -d% -f1 | awk '{ print $(NF) }'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df -k | tail -1 | sed 's/.*\([0-9]\+\)%.*/\1/'
```

use regex match